# Crash of Duke Nukem Forever in Ubuntu Steam - Proton experimental - Nvidia RTX 3060

Tags: steam, linux, graphics-card, ubuntu, duke-nukem-forever

I have an issue. My old laptop died and I bought a new PC with a MAG B550 Tomahawk motherboard, a Ryzen 5 5000 with Radeon and a NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060.

I installed the latest Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and Steam - SnapStore 1.0.0.76. When I run the Duke Nukem Forever with compatibility mode using Proton experimental for the first time it worked smoothly.

However, I realised that I was using the ATI Radeon chip-set instead of the actual NVIDIA card. I installed the NVIDIA proprietary drivers from Ubuntu > Additional Drivers>  535.54.03, and when I try to run the game it crashes after loading the Vulcan plugins, and a screen pops up to report the error.

Do you have any idea how to solve this please?

**EDIT:**

Just to add more details, I tested all the proton versions from 5 to 8 and Experimental, and it does not work. I tested other games like Duke Nukem 3D World Tour (Success) and Fullthrotlle, Quake 2, etc.

I tested some parameters like PROTON_USE_WINED3D11=1 %command% and still do not have any success, I followed some recommendations from here  https://www.protondb.com/app/57900 , and nothing

I would not like to revert the video card driver just to play one funny game. Help please.

**EDIT 2:**

I thought that the splash or video intro was the issue, so I added the parameters -nointro -novid  and I thought that it was a resolution issue because I am using a 34-in Huawei monitor.

No results, I ended installing Wine and running a Steam Windows version and it works.

[image]

[image]

[image]